# Strange UILabel and UIButton behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have a function called `change shape`:

```
- (void)changeShape {

    NSLog(@"**** CHANGE SHAPE ****");

    /* Set previous shape to current shape */
    self.previousShape = self.currentShape;

    /* Transition old shape out of view */
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4 animations:^(void){
        [self.shapeButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width+200, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {

            /* Set new current shape */
            self.currentShape = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.shapes[(arc4random() % [self.shapes count])]];
            [self.shapeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:self.currentShape] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            /* Transition new shape into view */
            [self.shapeButton setCenter:CGPointMake(-200, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^(void){
                [self.shapeButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
            } completion:^(BOOL completed){
                if (completed) {
                    [self changeScore];
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)changeScore {
    self.score++;
    [self.scoreLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.score]];
}
```

This function moves a UIButton off the screen, and then animates it back onto the screen. At the end of the final animation, I want to increment the score and change a `UILabel` on screen. For some reason, the image on the UIButton will only change after the UILabel has been changed. Does anybody know why this might be?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm saying that setImage seems to be executed after the completion block within the outer completion block. Get what I'm saying?

Answer (score -1):

Call `[self.shapeButton layoutIfNeeded]` after you applied position change and new image.

Comment: this sort of works. now the second uiview animation doesn't seem to be called

Comment: Again... Add `layoutIfNeeded` after you adjust coordinates inside the animation block.

Comment: this is not working. could you please elaborate on exactly where I should insert these line?

Comment: After you call `[self.shapeButton setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];` inside the animation block. Add same `[self.shapeButton layoutIfNeeded]`